# Is it possible a system recovery for non-bootable offline PC with bad-transitioned ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: boot, 18.04, lts, recovery-mode, offline

Some tutorial or method through a storage device like usb or sdcard to do a recovery and be able to replace corrupted essential files of the system, in  recovery mode and using command line interface.

UPDATE 1 : Corrupted LTS transition made networking function inoperative, CD drive is not working, it is not possible boot from USB, USB port operative but slow, SD Card port operative

Comment: You should go into some more detail of what's happened.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

The machine accepted a SD-card boot as a "USB boot", first with [Rescatux 0.51 beta 3](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/), a data rescue linux live distribution, executed some partition procedures and then, a SD-card boot with 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.6 for desktop  :)

More Details:

- I was random-searching linux distros in Distrowatch, and stumble upon [Batocera Linux](https://batocera-linux.xorhub.com/), a minimal retrogaming-oriented linux distro, which can be booted from a usb or sd-card.
- In the guidelines of Batocera, mentions [Balena Etcher](https://www.balena.io/etcher/), a software to flash usb or sd-card, and in this case, to flash Batocera to a sd-card (read the Frequently asked questions in [Balena Etcher Homepage](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) for doubts)
- Successfully sd-card boot with Batocera, but I was unable to access to terminal of Batocera or get internet in Batocera
- Try to sd-card boot with the 64-bit Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop, but does not work
- Try to sd-card boot with [Parabuntu-2016.11.1](https://www.parallella.org/create-sdcard/), but does not work
- Successfully sd-card boot with [Rescatux 0.51 beta 3](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/), and proceed to wipe out partitions and put others.
- Successfully sd-card boot with 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04.6 for desktop.

Comment: Is this an answer to your question? It looks like things you have tried. Is your question now solved?

Comment: Yes is the resolution

Comment: By the way if you have some issues with the redaction of the answer, please tell, composition is not my strength. On the other side, I answer myself, because besides find the answer, it can be very valuable for others, It is not just post for the sake of post things, which is great, but for its value ;)